# InitCommonControlsEx() fails with ICC_LINK_CLASS in Windows 8.1

Tags: c++, winapi, hyperlink, common-controls, createwindow

I'm trying to put a simple hyperlink on my window.

```
INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX iccx;
iccx.dwSize = sizeof(INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX);
iccx.dwICC  = ICC_LINK_CLASS;   // CommCtrl.h: #define ICC_LINK_CLASS 0x00008000
bool bResult = InitCommonControlsEx(&iccx); // bResult is false.
DWORD dwError = GetLastError(); // dwError is 0.

hWnd = CreateWindowExW( /*_In_      DWORD*/     0,
                        /*_In_opt_  LPCTSTR*/   WC_LINK, // CommCtrl.h: #define WC_LINK L"SysLink"
                        /*_In_opt_  LPCTSTR*/   L"Hello World",
                        /*_In_      DWORD*/     WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_TABSTOP,
                        /*_In_      int*/       50,
                        /*_In_      int*/       200,
                        /*_In_      int*/       100,
                        /*_In_      int*/       20,
                        /*_In_opt_  HWND*/      hWndParent,
                        /*_In_opt_  HMENU*/     NULL,
                        /*_In_opt_  HINSTANCE*/ hInstance,
                        /*_In_opt_  LPVOID*/    NULL);
DWORD dwError = GetLastError(); // hWnd is NULL and dwError is 1407.
```

The error code 1407 is explained in [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681385%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) as follows.

```
ERROR_CANNOT_FIND_WND_CLASS
    1407 (0x57F)
    Cannot find window class.
```

I'm using Windows 8.1 Pro x64, and I have never tried this code on any other version of Windows.

What is the problem here?

Comment: Did you forget the Common Controls 6 manifest? SysLink controls require Common Controls 6.

Comment: @andlabs First time hearing it. I will google it now. Thanks.

Comment: After a little internet research, I was able to solve my problem by adding the code `#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")` just after including CommCtrl.h by `#include <CommCtrl.h>`. Yet, I don't know the explanation of what I did.

Comment: That line instructs the Microsoft linker to add a Common Controls 6 manifest. See [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more details. Windows requires you to do this to opt into the new version of the Common Controls library [for backward compatibility reasons](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/01/29/7294949.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

As you have figured out, adding

```
#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
```

is one way to fix the problem.

The SysLink control was only added in Common Controls version 6. For [backwards compatibility reasons](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/01/29/7294949.aspx), Common Controls 6 is NOT enabled by default. You have to opt into it by creating a manifest.

A manifest can exist as either a separate file (named `program.exe.manifest`) or as a resource with a specific resource ID. The `#pragma` line tells Microsoft's linker to generate the second one for you. You can also produce either form on your own. [Here's how.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)